# I just want to read last ten characters from a barcode scanner input

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode-scanner

I want to read only the last ten characters from the barcode input in the windows form application. how to do that please help me.?

I developed a windows form application using c# which shows the barcode input in the textbox and in the label.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: FYI A barcode scanner is usually detected as a keyboard, and operates as one.

Comment: I created three text boxes and a label in windows form application and by threading tasks. I can read the barcodes by scanners in textboxes then by clicking the label i see the desired reading.

Answer (score 0):

Barcode Scanner automatically scans the code. Once you get the code in textbox use `substring` to get last 10 digits of the code.

Comment: How to use substring in c# and can you provide the code for a windows form application, such that when the end user put the cursor in a textbox and scan the code using scanner he should see only last ten charcters of the barcode data. Please help me

Comment: Fetch textbox data into some string, then perform substring and assign that to textbox again.  `String TextBox = "ABC1234569871";
  TextBox = TextBox.Substring(TextBox.Length-10);
  `

Comment: Can you please explain me in detail, now i have to create a windows form application with a textbox then connect the scanner and reads the data in that textbox then how could i get last ten charcters from that data?